# Mouse lag after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, video, mouse

I was running Ubuntu 13.10 with no issues and decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 recently. Since I've upgraded I've noticed that my mouse starts to lag after I play a movie via xbmc or a video on Youtube in full screen mode.

It usually happens after playing a fullscreen video for around an hour. My mouse works perfectly on startup.

I have just tried a fresh install of 14.04 and I've got the same problem.

When I say the mouse lags, I mean that after I move the mouse it takes 1-2 seconds to respond and is continuously lagging ie. once it starts lagging it's constant and I have to reboot to fix the problem. I've tried restarting x but that doesn't fix it.

I am using a Logitech K400 mouse/keyboard combo with a logitech unified receiver.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [OP decided to downgrade](http://askubuntu.com/a/460847/169736)

Comment: dont downgrade just give a snapshot for your drives

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I actually found the issue to this problem and thought I'd do the right thing and post it. It would seem that the positioning of the bluetooth receiver in particular USB ports had an impact with the reception between the keyboard/mouse (probably something to do with the fact that it's a mini-pc and the processor and other radio affecting devices are situated so closely together and so close to the USB ports).

I changed the logitech bluetooth receiver to a different USB port and my mouse/keyboard are working like a charm now.

Thank you to everyone for their input and help!

Comment: Thanks. Thought it might be something to do with the drivers. But simple switching of receiver to another USB port fixed it.

Comment: Very interesting that this worked for me with a Logitech G602 and the unified receiver. I wouldn't have thought to try it if not for this thread. I was actually on BunsenLabs (Debian-based distribution) and the solution was the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, but i fixed it. You need to install "CompizConfigSettingsManager" and switch off "sync with VBlank" in OpenGL tab. After that i installed PPA and update drivers for video card. It helped me. Here is video solution: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIQZv6MXzno

Comment: Thanks for your response but this answer is related to graphics performance, not mouse lag.

Comment: I had problem with windows rendering and applications speed. Mouse lagging was just one side of the issue. Good luck.

Comment: I experienced severe mouse stuttering also, and disabling "Sync with VBlank" fixed the issue.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this; it seems to have fixed my problems with lagging keyboard and mouse input on 14.04. I didn't need to update drivers; I had a big improvement by just installing ccsm (apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager) and disabling the "Sync To VBlank" checkbox. To find the checkbox, run the command 'ccsm', and click "General > OpenGL"

Answer (score 2):

This can occur if your bluetooth dongle is next to a wifi chipset for example. Just switch side to connect my USB dongle solved my laggy keyboard (my mouse was already fluid before).

A fresh install rather than a upgrade is always cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a solution to my problem so I am going to downgrade to 13.10. This is a real shame since I would have liked to run a LTS release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Do not despair. It is normal to have incompatibilities and bugs in any release, LTS or not. You can always install some of the follow-up releases of the LTS (14.04.x when they become available) where (I'm sure) most of the bugs will be ironed out.

Comment: Thanks for your response. FYI, I re-installed 13.10 and my mouse issues are non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

This solved this problem, although kernel dowgrade is not a good thing:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.4.0-3-goldfish
```

Comment: If it works then it's good enough. Newer isn't always better my friend.