# Radeon HD 8490 Video Driver Problem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, multiple-monitors

I have a problem with running Radeon HD 8490 video card in Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to set up dual monitors so here are my problems. When I go to System Settings - Software & Updates - Additional Drivers, there are 3 available drivers for my video card. The default selection is " X.OrgXServer - AMD/ATI dispay driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati (open source,tested) ". When I use this driver, I have to monitors but the keyboard has considerable lagging problems. So I switched to the proprietary driver " Video driver for AMD graphic accelerators from fglrx (proprietary) ". The keyboard operates correctly now and I still have two monitors, but this driver produces considerable lag in the mouse. I tried the solution presented here [Mouse lag after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460477/mouse-lag-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-14-04) that said to run "CompizConfigSettingsManager" and uncheck "sync with VBlank". This suggestion didn't help. So I switched to the third available driver " Video driver for AMD graphic accelerators from fglrx-updates (proprietary) ". The keyboard and mouse now function properly but my second monitor is not recognized. So here is the summary:

1. Open Source Driver --->   lagging keyboard
2. Proprietary Driver --->   lagging mouse
3. Proprietary Driver Updates --->   only 1 monitor

And suggestions on how to fix these issues? I'm not particular about which driver I use, just so long as nothing lags and I have 2 monitors. Thank you all.

Update: 1/14/2015
I updated my Bios Version from A03 to A08. Now, the keyboard is always fine. When using the Open Source Driver, I have two screens but the mouse lags. When I use the Proprietary Driver or the Proprietary Driver Updates, the mouse functions fine, but I only have 1 monitor.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my computer has two Radeon HD 8490 video cards. Ubuntu only recognizes one of the video cards. So in using the first video card, there are two ports DisplayPort and HDMI. I connected both monitors to the same video card and now they both function.

Continuing Problem: The proprietary drivers only recognize 1 of the 2 available video cards. I've found a similar topic [here on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230739).