# Logitech wireless keyboard lag

Tags: keyboard, logitech

I have the Logitech Wireless Combo MK270.

Quite frequently the keyboard will become unresponsive, or lag for anywhere between 30 seconds to 2 mins.

I've figured out that unplugging and re-plugging the usb fixes it.. But I would like to just fix it entirely.

It's not a hardware issue, because it works fine on windows.

Answer (score 7):

Definitely receiver placement. I have my laptop mounted on the back of my big monitor and use the laptop monitor as a second screen that sits on top of the external one. If I put the receiver on the left USB everything gets wonky. On the left it sits between the HDMI and aux cables and I think that is part of the problem with the additional distance. But if my laptop is just sitting on my kitchen counter, I can use the mouse/keyboard from 10 feet away no problem.

Also make sure your phone is not near (12 inches-ish) or directly between keyboard/mouse and receiver. When mine lags, I just mindlessly look for my phone and move it and all is good again.

I *think* it's the bluetooth on the phone but phones kick out a lot of junk so not sure. I'm not going to start turning BT off just to resolve this so never tested this theory.

Comment: My (cheap) VZTEC 2.4GHz RF-based keyboard becomes laggy whenever I put my phone close to it (less than 1 meter) even when the bluetooth is off. So yeah, it's better keep your gadget away from it

Comment: Also using the Logitech keyboard+mouse combo. Very slow response. Moved the bluetooth adapter from usb port next to hdmi port to usb port next to lan port. Problem solved. Apparently, the metallic hdmi plug at 2 millimeters flat against the bluetooth adapter ruined the bluetooth signal. In the new position the corner of the bluetooth adapter is about 5 millimeters away from the corner of the hdmi plug. The bluetooth adapter is now flat against the plastic RJ45 plug but this seems not to weaken the bluetooth signal.

Comment: For me what worked was, moving the receiver from a USB slot next to the HDMI port to one next to the network port on the other side. I checked with the phone placement near the receiver but that didn't seem to introduce the lag in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Another user reports that the positioning of the receiver could make a difference (see https://askubuntu.com/a/589132/89042).

I just tried moving the receiver to one of the USB ports in the front panel of my desktop PC and it seems to have improved (I have tested it for only few minutes so far, though). Mine is a Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Keyboard/Mouse combo.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure about placement of the receiver as much as the bus it physically on. I was having similar issues - erratic behavior with a MX Performance mouse under 14.04. Tried lots of suggestions including upgrading to 3.19.0.xxx kernel, little seemed to work.

What I do recall was the receiver was on one of the "ports on the back of the machine".... looking into that It was worse, attached to an unpowered USB hub with several other devices. I simply moved it to a "front panel" port and it hasn't crapped out since. Plugging an ordinary corded mouse into the machine seemed to work fine - and at that point I was pretty sure it wasn't driver related.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. It turned out that it was due to a USB hub that I'm using. If I plug the keyboard's USB receiver directly into the computer it works without lag or delay. No idea why it wasn't a problem with Windows. This just in case someone else comes across this thread with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

To Debug the issue try removing the wireless mouse or keyboard and replacing with a wired version. It worked for me per Wired mouse Works AOK now without odd random wireless mouse hangs.

Planning to monitor for any other issues like so:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i "perf: interrupt took too long"

[50786.060135] perf: interrupt took too long (2504 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750

[109527.659324] perf: interrupt took too long (3132 > 3130), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63750
```